# Can not go to the router admin page through 192.168.1.1

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, router, network-adapter

Just install the router and can not access to router admin page

when I go to cmd and type ipconfig, it show something like

```
ipv4 1.64.23.97
child network mask 255.255.255.255
default gateway 0.0.0.0
```

Any hints to the problem and how to fix it? I am using windows 7 , thanks

**Update:**

Notice that the network has no problem, I can access other website only can not go to the router admin page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your router is not operating correctly, or your router and your computer cannot communicate.

You have an "auto-configured" IP address and no gateway, which means that Windows tried to get an IP from your router, but did not get a response from your router.

Try resetting your router, and double-check that the appropriate lights are on indicating that there is a good connection between your computer and your router. After connecting your computer and your router, you should have a network mask of `255.255.255.0` and the default gateway should be the router IP address (typically `192.168.1.1` or `192.168.0.1`).

Comment: when I reset the router still the same, any other approach ? thanks a lot

Comment: Can you include the full output from `ipconfig` ? `0.0.0.0` is not a valid ip address, and generally means "everything"

Answer (score 1):

Try using your default gateway 0.0.0.0

Comment: in chrome it will redirect to the search result

Comment: Have you tried http://0.0.0.0/